# Getting rid of the margin between list style type and text

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Well, thats the html code:

```
<ul>
  <li>first item</li>
  <li>second item</li>
</ul>
```

And the css:

```
ul, li { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
```

Nothing fancy, right? And nothing to be proud of, it just shows a list without any margins or padding. Well, almost...

[image]

What about this space there? I can't seem to get rid of it. Any ideas? :]

Comment: @pawel: totally edited my answer. previous code didn't really work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to remove the space between text and bullet, you got to change the HTML-code a little bit:

```
<ul>
  <li><span>first item</span></li>
  <li><span>second item</span></li>
</ul>
```

By giving the li a relative position and the span an absolute position, you can move the span to the left:

```
li {
    position: relative;
}

li span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hack around to get it working, but maybe you might want to consider removing the list-styles and use a background on your `<li>` instead, like that you'll have total control over it.

A good reference about that: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/

W3Schools : http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_list.asp

Comment: I don't think this is what Paweł Mysior meant. He wants to remove the space between bullet and text -- I see you updated your answer, never mind ;)

Answer (score 2):

The only reliable cross-browser way to achieve this is by dropping the bullets altogether and using background images on your `li`s instead. This works in all major browsers (even IE5 and Netscape 7.1) and does not require any changes to the HTML itself. See [Listamatic](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/vertical05.htm) for an excellent guide.